"Updates" column in maven dependency's description page on mvnrepository
I am trying to find out what the column Updates means in the below screenshot.

Can I update those transitive dependencies e.g spring-security-config higher than 6.3.1, using spring-boot-starter-security 2.5.3? Or it won't be compatible?
I just want to know what that column means.

I would check first: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x also that you have upgrade from 2.X to 6.X which means 3,4,5 and 6 major upgrades.. you should check first and read the docs about that...

Why not upgrade the direct dependency you're using first? spring-boot-starter-security has a version 3.3.2 available according to your screenshot. Also, when it's about Spring, you should use a BOM provided by Spring that will make sure you have compatible versions across all the dependency tree.

That column just reports the latest published version of that specific artifact; it does not mean that you can update seamlessy to that version in your application. In this case, updating the dependencies to that version keeping the 2.5.3 spring security artifact will quite surely make your application unrunnable.
I usually read that column to understand how "old" the dependencies of the artifact I want to use are, and if there may be conflicts or some exclusions that have to be put in the pom dependencies.
